# A Quadrilateral (The National Mathematical Olympiad in Bulgaria)

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

**Problem**: We have the quadrilateral $ABCD$. The middles of $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ and $DA$, are respectively $M$, $N$, $P$ and $Q$. The centroid of $BNP$ is $F$, and the centroid of $NPD$ is $G$. $MG$ intersects $FQ$ at $K$. We know that $FK = 6$ and we have to show $KQ = 9$.

[image]

I made а diagram, but I need some help.

Comment: The algebra of vectors helps.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, can you be more specific?

Comment: I'll show it In evening.  Just I am very busy now.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, can you show it now because I don't understand how to prove that KQ = 9. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\frac{GT}{DT}=\frac{1}{3}=\frac{FT}{TB},$$ we obtain $$GF||DB$$ and $$GF=\frac{1}{3}DB.$$
On the other hand, $$QM||DB$$ and $$QM=\frac{1}{2}DB.$$

Thus, $$GF||QM$$ and $$GF=\frac{2}{3}QM.$$
Id est, $$\frac{FK}{QK}=\frac{GF}{QM}=\frac{2}{3} $$ or
$$\frac{6}{QK}=\frac{2}{3},$$ which gives $$QK=9.$$

Comment: Much Appreciate to your help. But why when we know this:
$$\frac{GT}{DT}=\frac{1}{3}=\frac{FT}{TB}$$
=> GF||DB?

Comment: @Nikol It's the Thales's theorem.

Comment: We haven't studied it. I am going to read about it. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: You are welcome!